# Using a function to call a functor

Tags: c++, coding-style, functor

I have an algorithm that calls several functions to process its data.  Each of these functions share and manipulate many of the same variables.  Therefore I'm trying to avoid having a set of functions that contain a long list of reference arguments as I find that to become very difficult to read, especially since many of these variables are STL containers.  As a result, I have implemented a functor to perform the work of the algorithm and defined a function wrapper for the functor, as shown below

```
class myfunctor {
private:
   ... list of shared members ...

   void A(..args..) { ..do some work on shared members.. } 
   void B(..args..) { ..do some work on shared members.. }
   void C(..args..) { ..do some work on shared members.. }

public:
   void operator()(class1& X, class2& Y) {
      A( .. );
      ..
      B( .. );
      ..
      C( .. );
      ..etc.. 
   }
};

void algorithm(class1& X, class2& Y) {
    myfunctor obj;
    obj(X, Y);
}
```

I'm just curious to see if there is perhaps a better way of implementing several functions that all depend on the same variables, and if this is considered bad practice?

Comment: @anon - Ah, I've never noticed those before.  Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Why make this a functor instead of a function? And if the argument lists are really so unwieldy, why not have `A(class1& X, class2& Y)`, `B(class1& X, class2& Y)` etc.?

Comment: How are X and Y used inside your functions.  In this code sample it's very unclear what you're trying to do - can you give a more concrete example?  From your description it sounds like the functions should just be member functions.

Comment: Yes, it's all about how concepts fit together. It might make sense for you to wrap all those variables those functions are manipulating up in a class that you then pass to the functions. Or maybe those functions make sense as member functions. It all depends on details. The goal is to communicate to other people what your program is doing, and a bunch of anonymous names for things isn't going to help us tell you how to communicate better in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With umpteen functions working on the same shared data, making them member functions of a class with the data as instance data is the rational choice.

However, “functor” is perhaps not the correct term for your beastie.

A *functor* behaves much like a simple function pointer: it can be freely copied around, and usually, from the caller’s point of view, doesn’t appear to change state. While your beastie apparently cannot be freely copied around, and does appear to change state. I’d say your beastie is more like a *state machine* object, brought from state to state by the function calls.

Cheers & hth.,